# y as a function of x in R

Tags: r

I have a complex function of y in terms of x as below

```
y = 1-(e^(-((x^2)/730)))
```

or y equals 1-(e power minus (x-square/730))

How do i represent such complex functions in R? I want to draw a curve(graph) connecting all these points. I also want to mark x-axis from 0 to 370 with interval of 10. I know how to keep the breaks, but i don't know how i can label axes with numbers. If help is given somewhere, please guide me to that link. Much appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you seen the [curve](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/curve.html) function?

Comment: if i can represent y in terms of x, i can simply do plot(x,y) or some functions. But how to give in R the expression for y?

Comment: What documentation did you find when searching for 'plotting functions in R' on any popular search engine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the help for `?curve`, `?axis` ...

```
## draw the curve
curve(1-exp(-x^2/730),from=0,to=370,axes=FALSE)
axis(side=2)  ## add default lefthand axis
axis(side=1,at=seq(0,370,by=10))  ## add custom bottom axis
box(bty="l")  ## add a box
```

One thing to note is that R suppresses overlapping labels, so unless you have a very wide plot you won't actually see every axis label.  You can try adding `cex.axis=0.5` (or even smaller) to your side-1 axis if you like. You could also check out the `staxlab` function from the `plotrix` package, or [rotate the axis labels](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-create-rotated-axis-labels_003f).
(You had a lot of superfluous parentheses in your expression; more parentheses don't *really* hurt, but in the long run you can make cleaner code (and spend less time counting parentheses) if you learn the order of operations.)

[image]

Comment: +1 for the parenthetical pointing out excessive parentheses (itself containing a parenthetical remark).